# PHP - having a hard time understading why a certain value is echoed. Can an assignment take place inside of if and executed in else?

Tags: php

Hy to everyone ! 
Please excuse my ignorance, I'm so new to php.

I have a hard time understanding why a php code behaves in that way.
The code is working but I'm so clueless about why those values are echoed.

(The code has been simplified for explanation purposes but it would normally populate and format a table based on a custom number of columns)

QUESTION *** 
   (see the code)

Why does the variable `$cell` echo (see: ?????? QUESTION ?????): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  ?
I was expecting 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 // because I thought the starting point for it would be  $cell = 0, as assigned at the start. The only rational reason would be that it inherits its value from $cell +=$i (from the for loop), but when the case is $col=2 isn't the first statement skipped entirely and only the else statement executed?

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <= 7 ; $i++)  {
    $cell = 0;
    echo "<tr>";

    for ($col=1; $col <= 2; $col++) {
        echo "<td>" ;
        if ($col == 1) {
            echo $cell; // echoes: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ----> because $cell = 0
            $cell +=$i;
            echo $cell; // echoes: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  ----> because of  $cell +=$i;
        } else {
            echo $cell ; // echoes: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7    ?????? QUESTION ?????
            $cell +=7;
            echo $cell; // echoes: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
        }
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Why did you write such a convoluted loop interaction? Just use the two output blocks verbatim, instead of for($col) and if($col). -- Regarding your question title, this is how PHPs variable scope works. You are accessing the same variable in both the if and the else.

Comment: Because he's new to programming...

Comment: So the  $cell +=$i in the if loop is not lost/ignored when the if condition is false, it just carries its value through the rest of the code. Right ?

Answer (score 5):

In the first iteration of the inner `for` loop, when `$col==1` then `$cell` is incremented by 1. When `$col` is other than `1` (the only other possible value is `2` in this case), then you already have incremented the value for `$cell` by `1` and therefore it stopped being `0`.

So you have:

```
i = 1 | $cell = 0 | $col = 1 // $cell +=$i; => $cell += 1; => $cell = 1;
i = 1 | $cell = 1 | $col = 2 // $cell += 7; => $cell = 8;
i = 2 | $cell = 0 | $col = 1 // $cell +=$i; => $cell += 2; => $cell = 2;
i = 2 | $cell = 2 | $col = 2 // $cell += 7; => $cell = 9;
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation ! So the $cell +=$i is not lost when the condition $col == 1 is false. It just carries its value through the rest of the code. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The reason for this is that `$cell += $i;` is the same as `$cell = $cell + $i;`, so what you are doing is changing the value for the $cell variable.

Answer (score 0):

$cell will never echoes 0 because when the second for loop starts $col will be equal to 1 therefore $cell will be $cell += $i which always its going to give you $cell == 1 because $i == 1 when code start runs. Hope this help

Comment: Thats wrong - it will echo zeros. first off: $cell=0 & $col=1, if $col==1, echo $cell.

Comment: Of course, but I'm talking about the question itself: (see: ?????? QUESTION ?????): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ? I was expecting 0 1 2 3 4 5 6)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `$cell` echo `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` and not `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` is `$cell` only increment in your 2nd for loop, and set back to 0 in your 1st for loop:

What really happens is:

for loop1

=> `$cell = 0;` // $cell is set to zero

for loop2

=> `$cell += $i;` // $cell is incremented by 1 
            => `$cell += 7;` // $cell is incremented by 7

with this scenario $cell being zero is only happening in **first for loop** or if you echo it **before** your increments.